# Not a valid cell/range reference when using indirect

Tags: excel, excel-indirect

I have 2 sheets and I want to show the value of a cell to the other sheet. The cell I want to show in the other sheet is `C26`and it has the value `€719.39` and the name of that sheet is `January`. In a cell in another sheet, I write

```
=INDIRECT('January'!C26)
```

and I have an error

```
Error Function INDIRECT parameter 1 value is '€719.39'. It is not a valid cell/range reference.
```

Why I am getting this error?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Try this, though I do not think it is what you want:

```
=INDIRECT("'January'!" & C26)
```

I think you want the simple formula:

```
='January'!C26
```

The [Indirect method](https://support.office.com/en-us/article/INDIRECT-function-474b3a3a-8a26-4f44-b491-92b6306fa261) is used to combine the value of a cell in a formula.  For example in this instance it would look for the cell reference by the value in Cell C26 on the active page.  So if that cell had the Value A1 it would return the value of A1 on sheet January.

If that is what you want then use the first formula.

But the second formula will return the value of cell C26 on the sheet January.

Comment: great it works. I google how to do this and I found that I had to use the `indirect` command.I misunderstood its usage...  thx!

Answer (score 1):

Indirect uses text input so it is either in quotes or refers to a cell where there is text.

```
=indirect("January!C26")
=indirect("January!"&"C26")
```

Put "January!" in C1 and "C26" in D1, for example, then:

```
=indirect($C$1&$D$1)
```

you could also use "row()" or "column()" with the address function (using r1c1 style):

```
=INDIRECT(ADDRESS(ROW(),COLUMN(),1,0,"January"),0)
```